# How to override a superclass __init__ argument?

Tags: python, superclass

How do I override the super class attribute?
In the example below, I want to use some other value for `name`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, config, address, phone):
        super(B, self).__init__(name)
        self.address=address
        self.phone=phone
        self.config=config
        self.name=self.config.name + "__value_only"
```

Comment: name is just the variable name. You can't change the attribute name of the base class from the inherited class. What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Pass `config.name + __value_only` to the super class constructor

Comment: @Vinny for the record, that's actually perfectly doable.

Comment: @jkm can you elaborate? how do you achieve that? metaclasses?

Comment: Just pass something other than `name` in the ` super(B, self).__init__(name)` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the desired "other" value to the `super(...).__init__()`. Also, `name` in your example is not a class, but an instance attribute:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, config, address, phone):
        super(B, self).__init__(config.name + "__value_only")
        self.address=address
        self.phone=phone
        self.config=config
```

Comment: Is there anything particularly wrong in defining it this way:
`    class B(A):
        def __init__(self, config, address, phone):
            self.address=address
            self.phone=phone
            self.config=config
            name=self.config.name + "__value_only"
            super(B, self).__init__(name)`

Comment: Nope, that would be fine as well.